# How to setup two servers inside one AWS ec2 with nginx and Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

How to setup two servers inside one AWS ec2 with nginx and Route 53?

Js server port = 5555, Spring app = 8888.

I have a domain name: xxxxxxxxxxxx.com

aws public ip yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

aws public dns zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

I need to set xxxxxxxxxxxx.com for js app

and api.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com for java app.

nginx

```
server {
#        listen         80 default_server;
#       listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz;
#      root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

What should I place in route 53?

I have only new hosted zone for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point both DNS in route53 to your **AWS instance public IP**, and handle both bases on hostname in Nginx config.

[image]

```
server {
  server_name xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:888;
  }
}
server {
  server_name api.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555;
  }
}
```